# Calculating vectors to create a given angle

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

From Anton's Elementary LA. I found this exact same question here on SE but the answer was not useful to me (it is incomplete and refers to arctan and methods that aren't in the text so far), so I'm hoping someone can point out my error.

**Let p = (2,k) and q = (3,5). Find k such that the angle between p and q is PI / 3.**

1. Cosine of $\pi$ / 3 = 60 degrees = .5.

   $.5 = (2,k) \cdot (3,5) / ||u|| ||v||$

   $(2,k) \cdot (3,5) = 6 + 5k$

   $||u|| = (2,k)^2 = \sqrt{(4+k^2)}$

   $||v|| = (3,5)^2 = \sqrt{9+25} = \sqrt{34}$

   $.5 = 6 + 5k / \sqrt{4+k^2} \cdot \sqrt{34}$

   $1 = 12 + 10k / \sqrt{4+k^2} \cdot \sqrt{34}$

   $12 + 10k = \sqrt{4+k^2} . \sqrt{34)}$

   $144 + 240k + 100k^2 = (4+k^2) \cdot 34$

   $144 + 240k + 100k^2 = 136 + 34k^2$

   $8 + 240k + 66k^2 = 0$

   $4 + 120k + 33k^2 = 0$

   $-120 +/- \sqrt{120^2 - (4)(4)(33)} / (2)(33)$

   $-120 +/- \sqrt{14400 - 528} / 66$

   $-120 +/- \sqrt{13872} / 66$

I'm not sure what to do with that 13,872 (I worked out it's prime factors, (2^4)(3)(17^2) and at this point it's obvious that I'm off track. The 7th step of doubling both sides looks suspicious but I can't see how that's wrong?

The textbook answer is -60 + 34(sqrt(3)) / 33. One thing I don't understand is why there is a single answer, shouldn't there be two due to the +/- in the quadratic formula?

ps: I can't get MathJax to work, I'm not sure why eg. 2 \cdot 3 displays literally?

Edit: add MathJax markup. Yep, didn't realize about the $ signs ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct. It simplifies to the answer Anton gives. The correct sign is obtained by graphing the two vectors. The quadratic formula does not distinguish between an angle of $\pi/3$ and $-\pi/3$.

Comment: I suspect MathJax did not work because you have to enclose maths in dollar signs.

Comment: Note that $2^2\cdot17^2=34^2.$

Comment: A thousand thank-yous. I will pay this forward somehow.